# Selecting rect's based on json and append rect inside selected parent rect

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg, d3.js

This will create parallel bars.

```
var bars = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "800").attr("width", "800");
var bars_section = svg.selectAll("rect").data(bars).enter().append("rect").attr("x", function(d, i){ 
    return i * 25 + 10; 
}).attr("width", "25").attr("height", "100").text(function(d){ 
    return d; 
}).attr("stroke", "black").attr("stroke-width", "3").attr("data-attr", function(d){  
    return d;
});
```

Now, will pass this JSON

```
var bar_data = [
    { name: "A", frequency: .08167 },
    { name: "B", frequency: .01492 },
];
```

Have to select rects created above based on bar_data.name - means only rect having **data** = A and B will get selected and then append rect inside it

```
bars_section.selectAll("rect").data(bar_data, function(d){ 
    return d.name 
}).enter().append("rect").text(function(d){ 
    return d.name;  
});
```

from first bars creation code - the o/p is this =

```
<svg height="800" width="800"> 
    <rect x="10" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="A">A</rect>
    <rect x="35" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="B">B</rect>
    <rect x="60" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="C">C</rect>
    <rect x="85" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="D">D</rect>
    <rect x="110" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="E">E</rect>
    <rect x="135" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="F">F</rect>
    <rect x="160" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="G">G</rect>
    <rect x="185" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="H">H</rect>
    <rect x="210" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="I">I</rect>
    <rect x="235" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="J">J</rect> 
</svg>
```

i need this o/p :-

```
<svg height="800" width="800"> 
    <rect x="10" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="A">A
      <rect>A<rect>
    </rect>
    <rect x="35" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="B">B
      <rect>B</rect>
    </rect>
    <rect x="60" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="C">C</rect>
    <rect x="85" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="D">D</rect>
    <rect x="110" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="E">E</rect>
    <rect x="135" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="F">F</rect>
    <rect x="160" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="G">G</rect>
    <rect x="185" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="H">H</rect>
    <rect x="210" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="I">I</rect>
    <rect x="235" width="25" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" data-attr="J">J</rect> 
</svg>
```

Comment: You can use [`d3.filter`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#filter) to restrict your selection to only the A and B `<rect>`s. However, nesting `<rect>`s is invalid anyway, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: actually , i have created rects inside which i want to create another rect which acts like a vertical progress bar in green color, depends upon frequency the height will differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bars_section.append("rect").attr("class","inner_rect")
```

I am no sure about whether **rect** inside **rect** is legal or not , but we can append **elements** inside **elements** like this

This will select each and every bar and will append **rect** inside it - that was my requirement

Comment: A rect inside another rect won't render.

Comment: kk, rect was just an example , i have used DIV inside DIV
Thnx for info :)